# How to create an object of a subclass, that extends another class, which is inside yet another class?

Tags: java, class, object, static, subclass

```
public class A{
      public static class B{
             public class B1 extends B{
             //it contains a constructor and some methods
             }
       }
         public static void main(...){
       //create B1 object here
       }
}
```

It works fine when I split the classes, but I need them in one java file. How would I create a B1 object in the main of class A?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: The `extends` is irrelevant, the relevant part is the nesting and which `class` is `static` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> `public class B1 extends B{`

This is a mistake.

inner classes have a secret, invisible field, of the type of their parent. So, your B1 class both extends B, **and** has a field of type B that has no name but is there anyway (and you need it to make any instance of B1). That cannot be right.

What you probably want, is:

```
public static class B1 extends B { ... }
```

Once it is static, you can simply write: `new B1();`, or if you haven't imported B1 directly, `new A.B.B1();`. Without it, you can only write `new A.B.B1()` in a context where there is some `this` reference that would refer to an instance of B: Such as in any non-static method of B. Outside of such contexts, you'd have to write e.g.:

```
A.B b = new A.B();
b.new A.B.B1();
```

in order to 'set' that hidden field (it will point to the same object the `b` variable is pointing at here). But... you don't want this. Now your B1 instance both is a B and holds a B, and that would be very confusing. Just make B1 'static'. In fact, make all inner classes static unless you both [A] are really really sure you need an instance inner, and [B] you fully understand how that works.

Answer (score 0):

to access non static inner class create object of outer class and access inner class using that object as below:

```
B b = new B();
B.B1 obj= b.new B1();
```

visit this [Java Inner Class (Nested Class)](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inner_classes.asp) link here and practice.